# How to load modules only when required

Tags: angularjs, module

I am doing angular project,i have a situation that i need to load "ngSanitize" module.The problem is i don't need this module when index page loading.I want to load it only when required.Please help to find out.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: @Sohiaib Farooqi How to use this. can u provide some example code.

Comment: https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

Comment: in that example you are adding a js file and how to add that module to myApp

Comment: post some code snippet of your problem so that I can guide more clearly. OR you can go through complete docs from the link in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate module file (app.module.js) in application depends on  your requiement...

```
    angular.module("SampleOne", []);
    angular.module('SampleTwo', []);
    angular.module("SampleThree", []);
    angular.module("SampleFour", []);
    angular.module('SampleFive', []);
```

On page loading initialize this module file,

Depends on your requirement call the modules in your application.

Here "SampleFive" is one of the module i have injected ngSanitize.

```
 var app = angular.module('SampleFive', ['ngSanitize'])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Message = "My name is <span><b>Angular Sanitize</b></span>";
    });
```

When we will call "SampleFive" module on a page only ngSanitize module will load.

Refer a below link...

[AngularJS Best Practices: Directory Structure](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

Comment: i have only one module called app. Can i inject the 'ngSanitize' into that module only when required

Comment: if you used one module there is no way to initialize ngSanitize when your required page, Create another module to inject the ngSanitize..it's one of the possible way...